# Admob: Could not initialize AdView: Required XML attribute "adSize" missing

Tags: android, admob

I follow the steps in the official link, and I can't find where is the problem. I have downloaded the libs from: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid 
This is my code:
In MainActivity i add:

```
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();   
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"                      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/lytMain"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cargando"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cargando resultados..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


   <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/progress"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:visibility="invisible"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Ver resultados" />


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is that a crash happening while running the app. If so post teh full stacktrace. Also Can you check adUnitId is correct or not ?.

Comment: In the log i have threadid=1: Could not initialize AdView: Required XML attribute "adSize" missing;   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41af1438)

Answer (score 1):

In the newest SDK:

XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Code:

```
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);    
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing this and use.

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample"
        android:id="@+id/add_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        ns:adSize="BANNER"
        ns:adUnitId="a14f1d807e488dd" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

 </Linearlayout>
```

Comment: and the adUnitId, isn't like ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx?